# Why is -webkit-keyframes not working in my SASS mixin?

Tags: css, webkit, sass, css-transitions

I have this SASS mixin that should make a button flash:

```
@mixin background_animation($color) {
  -webkit-animation: backgroundAnimation 800ms infinite;
  @-webkit-keyframes backgroundAnimation {
    0%      {background-color: $color;}
    50%     {background-color: red;}
    100%    {background-color: $color;}
  }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
@include background_animation(#000000);
```

However, it's not working. The background color of the button won't flash.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

P.S. The code works fine when not including it as a mixin.

The generated CSS looks like this:

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.800000011920929s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: backgroundAnimation;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);

... other rules omitted for brevity
```

Comment: What does the generated CSS look like?

Comment: It is not possible for the provided code to generate that CSS.

Answer (score 2):

SASS is not producing desired results after compilation. This is what you are getting which is wrong:

```
.box {
  -webkit-animation: backgroundAnimation 800ms infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundAnimation {
  .box 0%  {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .box 50%  {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .box 100%  {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
.box {
    @include background_animation(#000000);
}
```

Basically you don't want .box selector for keyframes.

Here is [**working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbFBW/) (Chrome)

**UPDATE**

You are taking slightly wrong approach here. Try this code snippet instead:

```
@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
  /*
  Other browser prefixes here
  @-moz-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }*/
}

@mixin animation($str) {
  -webkit-animation: #{$str};
}

@include keyframes(background_animation) {
  0%      {background-color: red;}
  50%     {background-color: green;}
  100%    {background-color: blue;}
}

div {
  @include animation('background_animation 800ms infinite');
}
```

It should compile to this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes background_animation {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }

  50% {
    background-color: green;
  }

  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
/*
Other browser prefixes here
@-moz-keyframes $animation-name {
  @content;
}*/
div {
  -webkit-animation: background_animation 800ms infinite;
}
```

Which produces [**this result in chrome**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbFBW/1/).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. Your fiddle is easy for me to understand. It's practically what I had before switching to SASS. The main problem for me is still passing at least one `color` to the SASS mixin. I still don't understand how to do that.

Comment: Check out updated answer. Hopefully that should help you out. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks again! Your code works but my problem is still that I need to pass a certain `color` to the mixin. As far as I can see you hardcoded `red`, `green`, and `blue` in there. But sometimes I need the effect on other elements and with one color being different, e.g. instead of `green` I need `orange`. Still trying to find a solution to that...

Comment: I think `$animation-name` should be `#{$animation-name}` in `@mixin keyframes($animation-name)`